# Dynamic resource injection in EJB3?

Tags: java, jms, ejb, code-injection

I know how to do resource injection to get JMS queue in EJB, just like the following sample, it's easy to get QUEUE1. But if I have lots of queue, and I don't want to change code when there is a new queue "QUEUE4".

Is it possible to get the resource dynamically or any suggestion for it?

```
@Stateless
public class OrderBean implements Order {

@Resource(name = "A.QCF", mappedName = "A.QCF")
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Resource(name = "QUEUE1")
private Queue QUEUE1;

@Resource(name = "QUEUE2")
private Queue QUEUE2;

@Resource(name = "QUEUE3")
private Queue QUEUE3;

    public String sendData(String abc) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Thanks for Gonzalo and bkail, the following is my solution:

EJB code: "QueueName" is a parameter from client.

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
Queue dynamicQueue = (Queue)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/" + QueueName);
```

ejb-jar.xml:

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <<resource-env-ref>>
            <resource-env-ref-name>Queue1</resource-env-ref-name>
            <resource-env-ref-type>javax.jms.Queue</resource-env-ref-type>
        </<resource-env-ref>>
        <<resource-env-ref>>
            <resource-env-ref-name>Queue2</resource-env-ref-name>
            <resource-env-ref-type>javax.jms.Queue</resource-env-ref-type>
        </<resource-env-ref>>
    </session>
</enterprise-beans>
```

When I have a new queue, I just need to change ejb-jar.xml and restart server.

Comment: Dependency Injection is itself dynamic. What do you mean by "dynamic resource injection"? Do you want the container to now figure what dependencies you want?

Comment: The queue name "QUEUE1", "QUEUE2", "QUEUE3", ... is hard code in EJB. I want to let it be a configurable value from parameter or read it from INI. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you'd have to do a explicit JNDI lookup so that you can dynamically set the resource you want to inject. Something like:

```
Queue dynamicQueue = (Queue)initialContext.lookup(dynamicQueueName);
```

where dynamicQueueName is the variable you set depending on whatever criteria you are using to figure out the queue name.

Comment: I think it's a workable solution and we already use it in our old applications (WebLogic). But because we're using OpenEJB to do test (still use WebLogic for production), I can use @resource in both but I cannot use context.lookup() to get resource now. I'll study it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to dynamically declare a resource-env-ref for a Queue (which is basically what the @Resource is doing).  That doesn't make sense:

[Jetty: adding <resource-env-ref> programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606327/jetty-adding-resource-env-ref-programmatically/5694220#5694220)

Comment: The <resource-env-ref> purpose is to separate the configuration between developer and deployer. For my case, it just let me to change the queue name in XML. But what I need is to add a new queue dynamically, not just change the mapping. Thanks for your reply, if I miss anything, please let me know.

Comment: Adding a new queue dynamically circumvents developer/deployer.  If you're going to do that, you might as well just lookup the Queue directly (rather than using @Resource or resource-env-ref), which is what Gonzalo suggested.  I suppose you might also be able to look up a QueueConnectionFactory, but I'm not a JMS expert, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Don't need to lookup QueueConnectionFactory because all queues use the same QueueConnectionFactory. But if the requirement is lookup QueueConnectionFactory dynamically, then lookup is necessary, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

READERS, there must be a more elegant answer than mine.

A static parametrisable initialisation, for instance from a resource bundle (.properties) file, can be done.
See [Andy Gibson](http://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/injecting-string-resource-services-with-cdi/). *(Resource bundles are cached by the way, but you can flush the cache.)*

I think you might mean having one object sending to a one out of a dynamic set of queues.
Personnally I would inject my own Queue Provider bean, self programmed.
Look at [Reconfigure your application at runtime with reloadable property files](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip125.html).

Comment: The reloadable property is useful. But because I want to "add" a queue dynamically, not change the queue. I'm not sure, maybe it's not for my case. But still thanks your reply, reloadable property is a good pattern for configuration data.